# What's the difference between dexedLibs and libs?

Tags: android, libs, android-studio

I'm moving from [Eclipse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=9438471#9438471) to Android Studio, and I'm importing my project.

I'm at the step where it's enquiring about libs in my old project. It has two sections, dexedLibs and Libs. Everything I had in my old project appears in dexedLibs, but a few also appear in libs. What is the difference between these two things? Should I remove the duplicate entries in libs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `dexedLibs` contains prebuild libraries of external libraries. This was introduced with ADT21 to enable faster building of projects. Before that, all external libraries were build every time you ran the project, but now they are built once and re-used. Duplicate entries in both folders *should* be identical and you can keep either of those.